# Hibernate does null check initialize lazy entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Say I have an entity Parent with a related entity Child (nullable) with a `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` relationship

In my action bean, would the following code initialise the child entity?

boolean hasChild = false;

```
if(parent.getChild()!=null){
    hasChild = true;
}
```

I see in the docs it says `Lazy collection fetching: a collection is fetched when the application invokes an operation upon that collection. This is the default for collections.` but wasn't sure if a null check is classed as an operation

Thanks

Comment: Related to your question: Have a look to the class "org.hibernate.Hibernate". There are all sorts of utility methods related to lazy objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a `null` check is not enough to reliably trigger lazy loading. You need to perform an operation that would require the presence of actual data, like calling `size()` on a `Collection` or any getter of your child object.

Please note that you will need to access the lazily loaded attribute inside a transaction.

It is not guaranteed that the lazily loaded attribute will not be loaded, even if you do nothing. `FetchType.LAZY` is only a hint to the persistence provider, so testing for lazy loading may result in fragile tests.

Answer (score 0):

Null check can initialize entity. Use Hibernate.isInitialized() instead.